How to find identityblob for a power bi paginated report
I am looking at this exmaple https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embed-token/generate-token#example-of-generating...
I can get my datasource from https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/group_id/reports/report_id/datasources. It's something like
{
"@odata.context": "http://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/group_id/$metadata#datasources",
"value": [
{
"name": "DataSource1",
"datasourceType": "AnalysisServices",
"connectionDetails": {
"server": "pbiazure://api.powerbi.com/",
"database": "sobe_wowvirtualserver-dataset_id"
},
"datasourceId": "datasource_id",
"gatewayId": "gatewayId"
}
]
}
But there's no identityblob from this endpoint. How can I find the identityblob. If it's not applied to my case, which case should I use among all exmaples
